# How to migrate InfluxDb to Amazon Timestream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, influxdb, telegraf, amazon-timestream

I have been trying to migrate my InfluxDb to Amazon Timestream. Since it is a new service, I am unable to find the exact documentation for migrating Influx to Timestream. I found that Telegraf can be used for connecting InfluxDB to Timestream, but couldn't find much information about migration. Can anyone share the steps for the migration? Any documentation is much appreciated.

Comment: did you get any inputs regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly Amazon Timestream, but now that AWS offers Amazon Timestream for InfluxDB you can migrate from InfluxDB OSS 2.x to Amazon Timestream for InfluxDB using the AWS Influx migration script: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-timestream-tools/tree/mainline/tools/python/influx-migration.

If you wanted to migrate all your data, including users, tokens, orgs, and dashboards, this command will do that:

```bash
python3 influx_migration --src-host <source InfluxDB 2.x host> --dest-host <Timestream for InfluxDB host> --full --confirm-full
```